# Mixing Objective C ,(*.m , *.mm & .c /.cpp ) files

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, objective-c++

In my project Core libraries are part of C/C++ files, while UI needs to be developed in Objective C, 
I am able to access/Call C++ functions from Objective C/.mm files 
but reverse no luck so far, i.e. i am not able to call Objective C functions from C++ Files, 
when i tried to include Objective C header even system header

```
#import <foundation/foundation.h>
```

getting around 1000+ compilation error,

something like this

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:180:0 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:180: error: expected unqualified-id before '@' token


/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:182:0 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:182: error: expected initializer before '*' token


/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:183:0 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:183: error: 'NSString' was not declared in this scope


/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:183:0 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:183: error: 'aSelectorName' was not declared in this scope
```

Am i missing some pre-compile flag etc.. 
can anyone suggest me, the best possible way to call/access objective C class which is inherited from NSObject, without modifying much C++ code, i just need to call one function

Code structure / Order to include header files are

```
Some system header file
Some Core Class Header file 

#import <foundation/foundation.h>
```

Comment: <foundation/foundation.h> should be <Foundation/Foundation.h>

Comment: @Bavarious:  although it will probably work as is because HFS+ is case insensitive by default.

Comment: @JeremyP Yup, hence _should_ instead of _must_. =) His code will break when compiled in a case sensitive filesystem.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you have a .cpp file with C++ code that needs to use Objective-C as well, either rename that .cpp file to .mm or pass `-x objective-c++` to the compiler.

Comment: how can we pass this parameter to the compiler? can we find this in project settings?

Comment: @some In that case, right-click the file on the project tree, choose Get Info and, in File Type, choose sourcecode.cpp.objcpp. This will tell Xcode to compile that file with `-x objective-c++`.

Comment: Using Xcode 4.6 I did this at the project level be setting `-x objective-c++` for "Other C++ Flags" and "Other C Flags" under "Apple LLVM Compiler 4.2 - Language" in the Build Settings tab for my project.

Answer (score 4):

I found it imposible to use any Objective-c in the C++ header files.

However, you can include Objective-c in the implementation files.

(.mm or you can set how to interpret .cpp files in the info of the file. Choose Info->General:FileType:Sourcecode.cpp.objcpp )

Use

cppClass.h:

```
class objcClass;

objcClass* mMemberVariable;
```

cppClass.mm:

```
#import "objcClass.h";

void cppFunction(){
    [objcClass message];
}
```

in the cpp header file.

Then include the header that defines the class in the .cpp or .mm file.

Comment: You can use Objective-C in a C++ header file, I am working on a project that does this.  The implementation is set as Objective-C++ in the Utilities->File Inspector and the obj-c code within the head is wrapped in #if defined( __OBJC__ )

Comment: I found you cannot declare any Objective-C classes in the header file without the file including it being a .mm file. In my case since my code needs to be cross-platform, I declared any Objective-C classes as ```void*``` in the header and then cast them in the .mm implementation file.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Qt, there is `Q_FORWARD_DECLARE_OBJC_CLASS` macro which can be used to forward declare an Objective-C class.

As a reference, here is the implementation:

```
#ifndef Q_FORWARD_DECLARE_OBJC_CLASS
#  ifdef __OBJC__
#    define Q_FORWARD_DECLARE_OBJC_CLASS(classname) @class classname
#  else
#    define Q_FORWARD_DECLARE_OBJC_CLASS(classname) typedef struct objc_object classname
#  endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a technique of the name expand files depending on a programming language. Also, I added "-x objective-c ++" to the compiler, but the problem remained. I was helped by council for the [link](https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/ofxfenster-not-compiling-on-osx/14141/2), pay attention to the "file type" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 11, it can be done by changing the build setting *Compile Source as* (GCC_INPUT_FILETYPE) to *Objective-C++* (sourcecode.cpp.objcpp). By doing this, there is no need to change the file extension type to mm.