# How to integrate aurioTouch app functionality in other app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to integrate aurioTouch app functionality in my app but I am having problems because few portion of that app is written in C++ and for this I changed my .m file into .mm but still having issues. I have added the image. Please see/ How this error can be resolved?

[image]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22514/discussion-between-ajit-thala-and-harsh)

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4714727/88461

> If you have a .cpp file with C++ code that needs to use Objective-C as
>   well, either rename that .cpp file to .mm or pass `-x objective-c++` to
>   the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and was unable to sort it out for a very long time. The real problem starts when you import the auriotouch's `.cpp` classes in to your project. Generally while doing that we face a lot of compilation errors and sometimes linker errors. So,

**First:**
Change the extension of all of your class files in your project from `.m` to `.mm`. This will make your class files to support both ***C++*** and ***objective C*** codes. **[If not, u'll face multiple compilation issues]**

**Second:**
Check whether you have imported the class files(`.m`, `.mm` or`.cpp`) in ***Project->Targets-> build phases-> Compile sources***.  **[If not, u'll face linker errors]**

**Third:**
Try to check whether u have properly declared the global variables in your class files. **[If not, it might show duplicate symbol error]**